# SaltStack file.recurse per minion

Tags: salt-stack

## Goal

How can I install files with [file.recurse](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.recurse) on the minion which are specific to minions?

## Current Strategy

This would works:

```
   files_per_minion:
      file.recurse:
        - source: salt://monitoring/files/per_minion/{{ grains.id }}
        - name: /
        - template: jinja
```

... but it fails for minions which don't have this directory on the master. I don't want to create a directory for every minion on my master.

I search for a way for an optional include. Here is a condition in pseudo code:

```
 {% if magic_way_to_check_if_source_exists salt://monitoring/files/per_minion/{{ grains.id }} %}

   files_per_minion:
      file.recurse:
        - source: salt://monitoring/files/per_minion/{{ grains.id }}
        - name: /
        - template: jinja

 {% endif %}
```

## Question

How to write the condition `magic_way_to_check_if_source_exists` ?

## Other solutions welcome

The condition `magic_way_to_check_if_source_exists` is just one strategy to get to the goal. Other solutions are welcome.

## Use Case

Imagine I want `cron_tab_file_for_xhost` to get installed, but only on the host called *xhost*. I could solve this by creating a directory tree and a file for this host like this:

```
monitoring/files/per_minion/xhost/etc/cron.d/cron_tab_file_for_xhost
```

Comment: whats written in those files? are they templateable?

Comment: @dahrens yes, we use jinja. See sample snippet in the question.

Comment: but you do not pass any data over to the file. if the file_per_minion only differs in lets say one value, i'd recommend to apply this value in your pillar and hand it over to the file - this way you do not need files_per_minion at all.

Comment: @dahrens I added an use case. I hope the question is more clear now. I don't think values in pillars help here. Except the boolean "this host has custom files in files/per_minion".

Comment: regarding cron i usually use the quite comfortable [salt.states.cron](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cron.html) - this also writes information into your crontab that manages the following lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways depending on your use cases and state tree.

The easiest one is to create a separate state and attach this using `top.sls`.

If you work on formulas, which are configured through pillar. I would write this information somewhere in my pillar. The states then decide based on the pillar data.

**pillar.example**:

```
yourformula:
  getspecificfile: true
```

**somestate.sls**:

```
{% if salt['pillar.get']("yourformula:getspecificfile") %}
files_per_minion:
  file.recurse:
    - source: salt://monitoring/files/per_minion/{{ grains.id }}
    - name: /
    - template: jinja
{% endif %}
```

**UPDATE**:

i just had a look in the [docs of the file.managed state](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html)

> The source parameter can be specified as a list. If this is done, then the first file to be matched will be the one that is used. This allows you to have a default file on which to fall back if the desired file does not exist on the salt fileserver. Here's an example:

```
/etc/foo.conf:
  file.managed:
    - source:
      - salt://foo.conf.{{ grains['fqdn'] }}
      - salt://foo.conf.fallback
    - user: foo
    - group: users
    - mode: 644
    - backup: minion
```

This seems to be another option - if you don't care to roll out empty files which are not necessary on your minions.

Comment: Yes, this is better than create an empty directory for all minions, which don't need this. Only few minions need "files_per_minion". But checking if "salt://monitoring/files/per_minion/{{ grains.id }}" exists would be even better....

Comment: A comment to your update (fallback to second source entry): Yes, this is a nice :-). I like this. I just need to put an empty directory there.... I guess this should work. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you again for the hint that you can supply two source files for `files.recurse`. I discovered that the fallback directory must not be empty. Otherwise you get this error: "file.recurse: Recurse failed: none of the specified sources were found"

Comment: I asked if the "file.recurse: Recurse failed: none of the specified sources were found" for empty directories is a bug or a feature here: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/37539